# Flutter Load users gallery photos and videos

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a screen which I want to load users photos and videos after getting permission to access gallery. After that I just want to have the screen that includes gallery photos and videos displayed in the screen and be able to play the video on another screen after tapping the video.

PS: I don't want the user to pick a video or photo and show it to the screen I want after permission the videos and photos to automatically load in the screen